# Proposed tag synonyms for decorators

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

These appear to be synonyms:

- [decorate](/questions/tagged/decorate)
- [decorated](/questions/tagged/decorated)
- [decoration](/questions/tagged/decoration)

And I suspect they are synonymous with these two tags that are synonyms:

- [decorator](/questions/tagged/decorator)
- [decorators](/questions/tagged/decorators)

Comment: Decorat* can mean about five different things in different contexts, but there don't appear to be any distinctions between the different variation on the word, that I can see. Should be safe to just retag them all `decorator`.

Comment: Browsing through those tags, I see several questions about decorated _names_, aka. name mangling. This has nothing to do with the decorator pattern, so they should be kept separate.

Comment: Have you dealt with [iterator], [iteration] and [iterate] yet, @Iterator?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Not yet, but perhaps on my next iteration, I will. :)  In reality, the reason I'm proposing synonyms is because I'm looking up some terms and get annoyed by having to search for multiple tags. Why would I search for iterators, when I understand them so well?  :)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Hmm, someone needs to suggest those as synonyms (iterate, iterative, iterating, iteration, at least; iterator/iterators could be different).  Do you want to do it?  I feel it might be a bit ironic of me to suggest it.  :)

Comment: @Iterator: That's often why I retag or synonymize!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I retagged all of the [decorate](/questions/tagged/decorate), [decorated](/questions/tagged/decorated), [decoration](/questions/tagged/decoration) questions.

There were three groups:

1. Remove the tag completely. It was unhelpful.
2. Change the tag to [window-decoration](/questions/tagged/window-decoration) or [name-decoration](/questions/tagged/name-decoration). These can easily be retagged if someone comes up with something better, as there are only a few of each.
3. Changed the tag to [decorator](/questions/tagged/decorator).

Comment: +1 Good job, but don't we have computers that can do that?  ;-)

Comment: @Iterator what do you think, should the `name-decoration` questions just be retagged `name-mangling` which is a far more popular term, even if they don't use it?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't have any expertise on name-mangling.  Code-mangling, data-mangling, text-mangling, perhaps...  name-mangling - no clue, sorry.  :)